# Mouse cursor freezes often

Tags: windows-10, mouse

When I move the mouse (a wired, optical mouse), it often gets stuck in the same point for several seconds, then jumps to a new location. This makes it very hard to navigate.

I thought it is because of high CPU usage, but the task manager shows only about 20% CPU usage.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the mouse?

Comment: @DavidPostill From the outside it is clean. Do you mean clean it from the inside? I do not know how to do this without breaking the mouse..

Comment: Read the manual for your mouse ...